# Expire Date and amount check using php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

current date is greater than expire date  and amount is null for the current date we have to set the reminder for payment .i tested

i checked on mysql current date is greater than expire date is  code is working fine

```
SELECT mid,planid,paid_date,expire_date,amount 
FROM payment 
WHERE expire_date < NOW()
```

code is working fine. only date expired.

but i need to calculate both condition expire and amount null value
if the person not paid after date expired those peoples names want to diplayed

but
what i tried far on php i attached below.

```
<?php
include("db.php");

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT  mid,planid,paid_date,expire_date,amount 
                        FROM payment 
                        WHERE expire_date < NOW() AND amount IS NULL");

$stmt->bind_result($mid,$planid,$paid_date,$expire_date,$amount);

if ($stmt->execute()) { 
    while ( $stmt->fetch() ) {
        $output[] = array ("mid"=>$mid, 
                            "planid"=>$planid,
                            "paid_date"=>$paid_date,
                            "expire_date"=>$expire_date,
                            "amount"=>$amount);
    }
    echo json_encode( $output );
}
$stmt->close();
//}
?>
```

Output displayed blank i don't what was the problem. it didn't show the member id and who are not paid yet.

this is my payment table

```
  id    mid     planid  paid_date     expire_date   amount
   25  1111    1      01-01-2021    06-01-2021        2000
   26  1111     1     08-01-2021    08-02-2021        2000
```

Comment: The query you tested and the query you are running in PHP are not the eame?

Comment: _Small Point_ As you have no bindable input parameters in the query you dont need to prepare the query, it adds nothing over a simple `->query()`

Comment: ya i test in php date expire is working fine. but amount is null is not working. if the person not paid after date expired those peoples names want to diplayed

Comment: SELECT  mid,planid,paid_date,expire_date,amount  FROM payment WHERE expire_date < NOW() AND amount IS NULL   this code tested through mysql also not shown output as i expected

Comment: how do the probler way to do this code sir

Comment: Well thats because `amount` is not NULL

Comment: ya. but the problem i got again Is not null. if the person paid the amount of current day still shown the member details.

Comment: Sorry I am not following

Comment: can you see the payment table i updatedd the payment

Comment: Is that the data on the database table OR the result you get from the query?

Comment: data in the database please help me sir.

Comment: So there are no rows where `amount IS NULL` So there will be NO ROWS in the resultset from the query

Comment: yes sir no rows shown if i put amount IS NULL

Comment: are they want modify any thing expire date and payment with php code sir rather doing on mysql

Comment: Sorry I am still not understanding what the problem is here,

Answer (score -1):

The problem with this query is you didn't compared with empty string. You need to check with both empty or null value,like this

> Select *
> From payment
> Where expire_date < NOW() AND (amount is null or amount = '')

Comment: Select * From payment Where expire_date < NOW() AND (amount is null or amount = '') not working same as blank shown

Comment: This is because there is **no blank or not NULLL amount** found. query is working with :                                                                                                                           id    mid     planid  paid_date     expire_date   amount
   25  1111    1      01-01-2021    06-01-2021        
   26  1111     1     08-01-2021    08-02-2021        NULL